# Having some problems creating multiple alarms on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-pendingintent

I am creating a todo application where the user can create a list of things to remember to do. When creating every instance in the list I set an alarm to go off when the entrys deadline is reached. The alarms reciever creates a notification, showing the user that the deadline is reached.

The problem I'm having is that the extra string I´m passing in the intent to the notification doesn't update properly. The first alarm functions well, but every entry I create following the first gets the same extra string passed with it as the first.

My code for setting the alarm is as follows:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(context, DeadlineActivator.class);
intent.setAction("todo" + System.currentTimeMillis());
intent.putExtra("todoname", name);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
        (int)System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, deadline.getTime(), pendingIntent);
```

Don't know if it is helpfull in any way but the name of the entry is unique

The onRecieve method for the alarm looks like this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String todoName = intent.getStringExtra(ToDoItem.TODONAME);

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent onClickIntent = new Intent(context, WatchToDo.class);
    onClickIntent.putExtra(Auth.TARGET_TODO, todoName);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, onClickIntent, 0);
    String body = "Deadline of " + todoName + " has been reached";
    String title = "Deadline reached";
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
     .setContentTitle(title)
     .setContentText(body)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
     .setContentIntent(pIntent)
     .setAutoCancel(true)
     .build();
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
}
```

When debugging, I see that the name var I use when creating the intent for the alarm has the correct value. The todoName var in onRecieve however keeps getting the old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem. You need to really understand how `PendingIntent` works. The problem is that when you call:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, onClickIntent, 0);
```

Android returns a "token" that can be used to launch `onClickIntent`. Android stores this `Intent` in an internally managed list and assigns the token to it.

The next time you call:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, onClickIntent, 0);
```

Android looks in its list of `PendingIntent`s to see if it has one that matches this one. Since the comparison of `Intent` objects **does not include the extras**, it finds the previous `onClickIntent` and returns the exact same token as it did the first time. You pass the token to the `Notification` and when the `Notification` starts the `Activity`, it gets the first set of extras.

To fix this you need to make sure that every call to `PendingIntent.getActivity()` returns a **unique token** and that Android is saving each separate instance of `onClickIntent` with the correct extras. To do this you can simply set the second parameter to a unique value, for example:

```
int uniqueValue = (int)currentTimeMillis();
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, uniqueValue, onClickIntent, 0);
```